# Why is higher update latency with more nodes in Google Cloud Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I used the provided [YCSB driver](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB) to benchmark the Spanner in Google Cloud Service.
For Spanner, I opted for Regional Configuration (instead of multi-region configuration) at Singapore (regional-asia-southeast1). So there are 3 replicas, one in each of three zones.
The benchmark workload is simple: first load 1M 1KB-size records (a total of 1GB storage) and then do the single-record update.

However, when setting the node number = 3, YCSB driver measures 17ms for update latency. When the node number is 12, it is reported for 49ms.

In addition, we follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/transactions) to benchmark on transactions updating two records. And we get a similar pattern (29ms with 3 nodes and 82ms with 12 nodes).

Since Google Spanner is a managed service, is anyone aware of this cause?

Comment: This is quite strange behavior, this normally work opposite way. Have you benchmark it on a testing database as in the YCSB instruction https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/tree/master/cloudspanner or you are troubleshooting existing database? And were have you run this driver?

Comment: I follow the YCSB instruction and I run the driver on VM instance.

Comment: Well, if indeed you are facing this I suggest to raise it to Google Support or Public Issue Tracker according to https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-support